# Retrieving random element in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class guessMovies {
private Random randomGenerator;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String MovieList = null;

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Movielist.txt"))) {

        while ((MovieList = br.readLine()) != null) {
            ArrayList<String> MovieNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            MovieNames.addAll(Arrays.asList(MovieList));
            //System.out.println(MovieList);
            System.out.println(MovieNames);

            Random r = new Random();
            System.out.print(MovieNames.get(r.nextInt(MovieNames.size)));
        }
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException exception) {
        System.out.println("I cannot find your file");
    }
    //pick random movie
}
```

Can somebody guide me on how to pick a random movie title in the Movielist file, I can print out the whole list, but I'm not sure on how to pick one of them randomly.

Comment: `System.out.print(MovieNames.get(r.nextInt(MovieNames.size)))` ... this is already very close to what you need.  What is the problem?

Comment: Put the line System.out.print(MovieNames.get(r.nextInt(MovieNames.size))); outside the read loop (and add parentheses() to size()).

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate one ArrayList, read all movie titles and add them to the list, then use Random.nextInt() to pick one and print it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public class guessMovies {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String MovieList;
        ArrayList<String> MovieNames = new ArrayList<>();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Movielist.txt"))) {

            while ((MovieList = br.readLine()) != null) {
                MovieNames.add(MovieList);
            }

            for(String movieName: MovieNames){
                System.out.println(movieName);
            }

            Random r = new Random();

System.out.println(MovieNames.get(r.nextInt(MovieNames.size())));
        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException exception) {
            System.out.println("I cannot find your file");
        }
        //pick random movie
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked, but now I cannot print out the whole MovieList file, it gives me "null"

Comment: @Troy Nguyen See my edited version above that prints the MovieList.  Alternately if you are using Java 8 you could replace the for each loop with MovieNames.forEach(System.out::println);

Comment: when I create Random r = new Random(); is it a string var? so I wanna use replaceAll method to replace the random name into "__"", but i cannot use var r, java said it cannot find the symbol.

Comment: When you create Random r = new Random(); you are creating an object of type Random, not a String.  MovieNames.get() method is what returns your String containing the movie name.  If you want to apply removeAll() to that to remove underscores, then MovieNames.get(r.nextInt(MovieNames.size())).replaceAll("_", "") would achieve that.